# Avoid duplication of ImageButton in Listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I am a newbie in android & developing my first ever app of Personal Diary.
Now I am having a problem in Listview, I have an Imagebutton in one layout which I want to behave like a header and I have some TextViews in another layout which I am representing as listview which are bound with database. Now the problem is that as many rows I get from the database as many button are generating which actually I don't want. I am using List Activity for generating listview out of textviews.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/detail_title_bar_2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnadd"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/add" />
    </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/detail_title_bar_2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtday"
                style="@style/Title_day"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:verticalSpacing="0px" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtmonth"
                style="@style/Title_Month"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:verticalSpacing="0px" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtyear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txttime"
                style="@style/Title_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understanded your question, you have a listview filled with entries loaded from a database und you want a button at the top of the list to e.g. add new items?

Then you can use the addHeaderView() function. Define your layout containing the image button as xml layout file, e.g. list_header_view.xml and add it to your listview:

```
View headerView = (View)inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.list_header_view, null);

listview.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

list_header_view.xml can contain:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/detail_title_bar_2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnadd"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/add" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Wawoo..!! I didn't think It would be so easy.. Thanks.. you saved my night :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't be afraid to use it as a separate component. If you use `ListView` correctly it won't be inefficient.

Here's some tutorial how to use `ListView's` from Google IO, by Romain Guy. It lasts over 50 minutes, but it's worth.
[Google I/O 2010, The world of ListView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)

The key part is about reusing created parts of `ListView` instead of creating new ones.

Then there's some useful info about finding `View's` in your `getView()` method. `findViewById()` method is something like searching in the tree - through your `Activity` layouts, then it's children, till the `View` your're looking for is found or not. This might be tough for device. So they suggest to use a static class called `ViewHolder`, to find place where parts of your layout are held only once. Not in every call of `getView()`